# Memory Leak Glassfish deployment

Tags: java, memory-leaks, glassfish

I've noticed that I have relatively large (about 50 MB per time) memory leak if I redeploy the application into Glassfish 4.1.1 on my Debian Linux 8.

By googling, I've explored multiple issues and bug reports with dates from 2007 to 2014 years that relates to memory leaks during the Glassfish deployments in different versions. There were some hacks [like this one](http://franke.ms/#glassfish4_1_1_memory_leak.wiki) (which are, unfortunately, does not work for me).

I cannot believe that there is no way to somehow cope with a problem. Does anyone give me a clue of where to look?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give more details on what you're seeing? 50MB is very small to point to a memory leak. Do you mean that redeploying a new version of an application causes the heap usage to increase by ~50MB? If so, that's not unusual. Those objects won't get cleared away immediately. Does it remain after a full GC?

Comment: I mean that 50MB per deployment. I'm monitoring it using visualvm and my metaspace size always extends when I perform redeploy. Using visual VM, I perform GC, but it decreases memory only a bit (about 10MB) and sometimes not decreasing at all.

Comment: By removing java thread (that were using thread.sleep() ) and placing all *.jars that are used into glassfish/domain1/lib directory it became possible to decrease memory leak from 50 MB to about 5-10 MB per deployment. But still, memory leak exists. I suspect java.util.logger (it is also using) and websocket's endpoint. Can they cause problems?

Comment: I know that we've put a few fixes into Payara Server (derived from GlassFish) around cleaning up deployments etc, so could you try the same test with Payara Server 162? http://www.payara.fish/downloads it would be interesting to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to do this.